# iOS Label prevent words from being broken up into 2 lines

Tags: ios, objective-c, uilabel

[image]

I want to allow multiple lines of text for activities with multiple spaced words, but adjust to fit width on single word activities, currently, this is what is happening as a result of this code:

```
    UILabel *label=[[UILabel alloc] init];
    label.font=[UIFont AvenirBlack:14];
    label.numberOfLines=2;
    label.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80);
    label.text=choice.title;
    label.numberOfLines = 0;
    UIColor *randomColor =[UIColor randomFlatColor];
    floatingImageView.backgroundColor=randomColor;
    floatingImageView.layer.cornerRadius=10;
    floatingImageView.clipsToBounds=YES;
    label.textColor=[UIColor colorWithContrastingBlackOrWhiteColorOn:randomColor];
    label.textAlignment=NSTextAlignmentCenter;


    //label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
   // label.backgroundColor=[UIColor blackColor];
    [floatingImageView addSubview:label];;
    label.frame=CGRectMake(10, 10, 80, 80);
    label.adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth=YES;
```

Comment: To be clear if there is multiple words then width 80 is fine but it there is one word you want to size it to the width of that word.  Should the minimum be 80 there (i.e. 'it' is small).  Also what do you want to do about the height?

Answer (score 1):

First determine the number of words in your string. If the number is 1, then set the `numberOfLines` to 1, else set it to 0. Also enable `adjustsFontSizeToFitWidth` on your label.